# How to distribute Google app scripts attached to a sheet to people selectively that are not part of the same G Suite Domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with attached Google app scripts. I want to distribute separate instances of the Google sheet along with the associated app scripts to selective users who are not part of my G suite domain.  The Google sheet is used to collect data that is exported via a Google app script to a CSV and automatically downloaded to the users local PC/Mac.  I create this sheet/script to facilitate a software onboarding process for new users of a SaaS-based real estate investor portal.  Making the script an Addon would be fine if I didn’t have to make it publicly available in the G Suite marketplace.  I understand that I could publish the add-on to my users if they were all part of my G Suite domain, but as mentioned above, they are not.  I was considering publishing as a web app, but the only web component of this app script is a modal dialog that is opened by clicking a custom menu item in the Google sheet, which I don’t believe will work as a web app based on my current understanding.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Making the script an Addon would be fine if I didn’t have to make it publicly available in the G Suite marketplace.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68qhP.jpg)

You don't have to. If you use the save the script a public an add-on you can release it with the link only. You'll still need app review. There is the option to not be on the addon store. [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project=[project-name]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project=%5Bproject-name%5D) is where the link is for me.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/how-to-publish